# Using multiple window.matchMedia in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)"),  window.matchMedia("(max-height: 479px)");
```

into my existing script right now which only has

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").
```

When I add the second `.matchMedia` the script doesn't fire at all.

Should I be adding multiple mqls?

Here is the script working before adding `max-height`:

> [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/)

Answer (score 0):

That's no valid Javascript. Just assign it to two different variables.

Or better combine the mediaqueries.

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px) and (max-height: 479px)");
```

Comment: I tried giving it to different var https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/2/ but can't seem to get it right

Comment: It looks like your js is minified in the fiddle. Can you provide an unminified version so I can better see what you're doing?

Comment: @jennEDVT ah, that's just TweenMax. The actual script is near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to store multiple values in a single variable. Did you consider using an array to do this?

```
var mqls = [ 
    window.matchMedia("(max-width: 8480px)"),
    window.matchMedia("(max-height: 497px)")
]
```

Then you should be able to iterate through the array to get your desired effect.

For more info, you could try checking out [this resource.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/matchmediamultiple.shtml)

Good luck!

Comment: I tried to follow that guide but didn't quite get it right https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/2/